# How to solve npm install -g cordova error under the Mac os v10.10.5 with npm -v2.14.4 and node -v4.1.1?

Tags: cordova

How to solve `npm install -g cordova` error under the Mac os v10.10.5 with npm -v2.14.4 and node -v4.1.1?

```
zhs -MacBook-Pro:~$ npm -v

2.14.4

zhs-MacBook-Pro:~ $ node -v

v4.1.1

zhs-MacBook-Pro:~$ npm install -g cordova

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0

npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"

npm ERR! node v4.1.1

npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! syscall rmdir



npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'

npm ERR!     at Error (native)

npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']

npm ERR!   errno: -13,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',

npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova' }

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'

npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)

npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']

npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,

npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'rmdir',

npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova' }



npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /Users/zhengbing/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 11):

**Updated answer**

1. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

3. In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

4. On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

5. To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

```
npm install -g eslint
```

See [the NPM docs titled "Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally" for more details](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

**Old answer**

You're trying to install cordova globally with the `-g` flag without root permissions, so you're getting an `EACCES` permissions error. When installing packages globally with the node package manager, you should have superuser permissions. Use:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

instead. You'll probably be prompted for your administrator password.

Comment: I’m such a noob, tnx :-)

Comment: Useful and short. Big THANKS.